# Next.js router is returning query parameters as undefined on first render?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, query-string

I've got a page on my Next.js app that does the following:

- It's a search page
- The pathname is like: `/search?q=search+slug`
- It loads data on the client
- It needs to read the `router.query` to get the `router.query.q` value

**PS:** I'm using Redux

```
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const router = useRouter();
  const query = router.query as { q: string };
  const queryString = query.q;

  console.log("SEARCH CONTAINER");
  console.log(`queryString: ${queryString}`);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(THUNK.LOAD(queryString));
    return () => { dispatch(ACTION.RESET_STATE()); };
  },[dispatch,queryString]);
```

See the `useEffect`. In theory is should run only once for every `queryString` (which is actually `req.query.q`).

But I was getting duplicated `THUNK.LOAD` actions. That's why I've added the `console.log()` there.

And this is what it's logging out:

[image]

And then:

[image]

And this is why I'm getting duplicated dispatches. Of course I can check for `if (queryString)` before dispatching, or maybe I can get it from `window.location.search`. But I am surprised the `router.query.q` comes as `undefined` on the first place. How is that even possible? Why would the `req.query` object be populated asynchronously? What is the explanation for this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just found out what is the solution to my problem:

From: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#router-object

> `isReady`: `boolean` - Whether the router fields are updated
> client-side and ready for use. Should only be used inside of
> `useEffect` methods and not for conditionally rendering on the server.

This is what happens to the `router.query` on client when you hit `/search?q=XXX`.

**1st render**

```
router.isReady: false
router.query: {}
```

**Subsequent renders**

```
router.isReady: true
router.query: {"q":"xxx"}
```

**Conclusion**

The fact that `router.query` is not populated on the client (for SSG pages) on the first run is a design implementation detail. And you can monitor whether it's has been populated or not by checking the `router.isReady` boolean property.

Comment: Can you elaborate this in class component ?

Answer (score 16):

[This solution](https://dpnkr.in/blog/nextjs-router-query-undefined#fix)  worked for me:

```
const router = useRouter();
React.useEffect(() => {
  if (router.isReady) {
    // Code using query
    console.log(router.query);
   }
}, [router.isReady]);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate this in class component? Also what If I try to pass the query to another component ?

Answer (score 3):

Building on @cbdeveloper answer, here is example code running NextJS for getting the router data during client-side rendering:

filename: `/pages/[...results].tsx`

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function Results() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { q } = router.query;

  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`useEffect triggered`);
    router.isReady ? setSearchQuery(q as string) : console.log('router is not ready');
  },[q]);

  return (
    <>
      <p>q: {router.query.q}</p>
      <p>searchQuery: {searchQuery}</p>
      <p>bar: {router.query.bar}</p>

      <form>
        <label>Search Query:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="q"
          value={searchQuery}
          onChange={(e) => setSearchQuery(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I ended up in this question because I've been trying to debug routing using catch all routes (pages/[...slug].js). When navigating from pages/index.js to a [...slug].js page everything works fine. But when I try to navigate from a  [...slug].js to another [...slug].js page (e.g. /careers to /blog) only the URL changes, but no rehydration or rerendering happen, do you have any possible solution?

Comment: This above example does not work for me using next 12.1.0. For some reason the useEffect hook gets triggered only once saying "router is not ready" and that's it.

Comment: `router.isReady` should be in deps of `useEffect` (`[q, router.isReady]`)

Answer (score 2):

That's because nextjs works on both server side and client side and it becomes necessary to check if you are actually on the server or client by doing something like `typeof window !== 'undefined'` because the component needs to be hydrated on the client side.

When you use the `useRouter` hook it runs only on the client side for obvious reasons, but when nextjs is delivering the "component" to the browser it has no idea what `router.query.q` refers to, it's only when the component gets hydrated on the client side the react hook kicks in and you can then retrieve the `queryString`

It is also similar to the reason why you would need to use `dynamic` importing in
your nextjs app for most client side libraries.

P.S. I'm new nextjs myself, but I hope this made some sense.

Comment: Thanks. Are you sure this is the reason? It kind of makes sense, but it's also weird why you'd need an extra run for the `useRouter` hook. Why wouldn't you make that `window` check on the 1st run right away?

Comment: I'm investigating it further. I think your answer is on the right track. It seems that Next.js initially gets the `query` object from `window.__NEXT_DATA__`, which is the prerendered data from the server. And if you didn't populate that on the server (probably by using a dynamic route or using `getServerProps`), the `router.query` obj will be empty on the first render. It will only read the query from your browser in a later render cycle. I don't know exactly when it happens, but it seems to happen automatically. I'm also asking it [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/24659).