# Passing query parameter to props of custom component in NextJS

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm currently making a profile page wherein the route `/profile/displaynamehere` will display a page where one of its components is a basic information page that shows the display name of the user.

The component is called `BasicInfo` and accepts props called `displayName`. Here's how it looks like:

```
export default function Profile() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const displayNameQuery = router.query.displayName;

  return (
     ...
     <BasicInfo displayName={displayNameQuery} />
     ...
  )
}
```

The problem is, `displayName` or `{displayNameQuery}` in this context is undefined whenever I try to console.log it. Is there a way wherein I can pass the query parameter as props to my component?

Comment: can you please share the code where you are setting ```displayNameQuery```  route? are you doing that using ```router.push()```?

Comment: `displayName` should match the file name as well. Since it is a dynamic parameter, your folder structure should be `pages/profile/[displayName].js`. Can you confirm if thats the case?

Comment: @AnkitSaxena No, Im not using router.push. I'm merely using useRouter from next/router.

Comment: @PsyGik Yes, that is how my page is structured

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Next.js router is returning query parameters as undefined on first render?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67332108/next-js-router-is-returning-query-parameters-as-undefined-on-first-render)?