# NextJS error in catch all routes when I try to find the route length

Tags: routes, next.js, next-router

I get this error when I try to catch all the routes

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.

Here's my code:

```
import {useRouter} from "next/router";
function Docs() {
    const route = useRouter();
    const {params} = route.query;
    console.log(params);
    
    if(params.length === 1){
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Docs {params[0]}</h1>
            </div>
          )        
    }

    else if (params.length === 2){
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Docs {params[0]} feature </h1>
            </div>
          )        
    }
    else{
        return (
            <div>
            <h1>Docs home page</h1>
         </div>
      )    
    }
}

export default Docs
```

Here's my folder structure:
[Project Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjWmd.png)

and I'm following this [Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZHn726VDoIY&list=PLC3y8-rFHvwgC9mj0qv972IO5DmD-H0ZH&index=9) for learning NextJS, Somebody help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Next.js router is returning query parameters as undefined on first render?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67332108/next-js-router-is-returning-query-parameters-as-undefined-on-first-render)? For pages that don't have data fetching requirements (like yours) the query string object will be an empty object during pre-rendering (meaning `params` will be undefined). You need to wait for `router.isReady` to be `true` before accessing the query params.

Answer (score -2):

Inside pages/docs just remove one extra bracket it should be like this `[...params].js`